# Displayed Data using foreach, on another #div using onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table like this:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Usernames</th>
      <th scope="col">number</th>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
     foreach($projects as $project)
     {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>'.$project['id'].'</th>';
        echo '<td>'.$project['user'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$project['number'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$project['user_type'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$project['logs'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="view-details" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="view_files" ">View</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to render the details of the table above on another div (shown below) in the same page but on another window view pane using the 'View' button.

```html
<div class="row my-4">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
    <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">Customers</h5>
      <div class="card-body" id="more-info">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          <?php echo $post['id']; ?>
        </h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          <?php echo $post['user']; ?>
        </p>
        <p class="card-text text-success">
          <?php echo $post['catch_code']; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `foreach` in the first example is been iterated with the "view" button for each element. I need each element to be displayed as I click 'View' on it. I was worried if clicking "view" then all elements will be displayed, being that the iteration is the same as the `id` on the View button..

Please kindly propose a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you're creating multiple elements with the same `id` in your loop. This is invalid as `id` values must be unique within the DOM.

To fix this issue change the `id` attribute to a `class` instead. You can then populate the 'View' link with `data` attributes that hold the information to populate the `#more-info` div when the button is clicked.

Try this:

```js
let $idField = $('h5.user-id');
let $userField = $('p.user');
let $catchCodeField = $('p.catch-code');

$('.view-files').on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $btn = $(e.target);
  let id = $btn.data('id');
  let user = $btn.data('user');
  let catchCode = $btn.data('catchcode');
  
  $idField.text(id);
  $userField.text(user);
  $catchCodeField.text(catchCode);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Usernames</th>
      <th scope="col">number</th>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>001</th>
      <td>User 001</td>
      <td>Number 001</td>
      <td>User type 001</td>
      <td>Logs 001</td>
      <td><a href="view-details" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary view-files" data-id="001" data-user="User 001" data-catchcode="Catch code 001">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>002</th>
      <td>User 002</td>
      <td>Number 002</td>
      <td>User type 002</td>
      <td>Logs 002</td>
      <td><a href="view-details" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary view-files" data-id="002" data-user="User 002" data-catchcode="Catch code 002">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>003</th>
      <td>User 003</td>
      <td>Number 003</td>
      <td>User type 003</td>
      <td>Logs 003</td>
      <td><a href="view-details" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary view-files" data-id="003" data-user="User 003" data-catchcode="Catch code 003">View</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="row my-4">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
    <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">Customers</h5>
      <div class="card-body" id="more-info">
        <h5 class="card-title user-id"></h5>
        <p class="card-text user"></p>
        <p class="card-text text-success catch-code"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually solved my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please, i just asked a question on how i can display a number of data using foreach, i love to see your inputs because it seems nobody seems to be getting it. Thanks